# Resizable Keyboard that Takes Only Right Half of Screen

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

**Problem**:
I forgot my Nexus 4 in the sun and now a vertical line like the one shown by the red line below is not responding to touches. The problem is that getting a LCD + digitizer replacement costs more than the phone and I couldn't find anyone willing to try replacing just the digitizer. The phone is still usable, but the problematic area stretches over the `e`, `r`, `d`, and `x` keys of the keyboard, which makes typing a huge pain.

[image: Nexus 4 showing unresponsive touchscreen area]

**Solution**: Having a keyboard that can be resized to only use the right side of the screen would be able to make the phone usable again. I have tried using SwiftKey's compact mode but it still stretches a bit much to the left, which makes the mode changing key, along with `a` and `q` unusable.

**Question**: Is there a keyboard application that allows resizing the keyboard so that I could have all of it on the right half of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The [Touchpal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cootek.smartinputv5) keyboard can be resized in any direction. This can be achieved by opening the application, going to `General settings`, then `Keyboard appearance` and then resizing as needed.

A further problem I faced was that I could not resize as it would require the use of the dead area of the touchscreen. I overcame this by using [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market) and resizing through my computer.